# I can not import TodoItem in Todos

Tags: reactjs

I can not import TodoItem in Todos. How to resolve this error?

This is my TodoItem.js file

```
import React from "react";

export const TodoItem = ({ todo }) => {
    return (
    <div>
        <h4>{todo.title}</h4>
        <p>{todo.desc}</p>
    </div>
    );
};
```

This is my Todos.js file

```
import React from "react";
import { TodoItem } from "./MyComponents/TodoItem";

export const Todos = (props) => {
    return (
    <div className="container">
        <h3>Todos List</h3>
        <TodoItem todo={todo[0]} />
    </div>
    );
};
```

This is the error in `./src/MyComponents/Todos.js`:

```
Module not found: Can't resolve `'./MyComponents/TodoItem'` in `'C:\Users\PrAbHu\Documents\React\to-do-list\src\MyComponents'`
```

Comment: Please show your structure code

Comment: By "structure code" I'm sure Viet meant how your src directory structure is organized. Where is `TodoItem.js` file located in relation to the `Todos.js` file?